# ip address configuration in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, internet, network-manager, iptables

1. I am unable to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/resolv.conf` file with `vi` editor. How can I access the file as a owner?
2. This is my network settings in Windows 7. I want to configure it in ubuntu 12.10. How can I do this?

   ```
   IP address 192.168.40.31
   Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
   Default gateway 192.168.40.1
   Preferred   DNS server 10.230.253.253
   Alternet DNS server 203.147.88.2
   ```

Comment: Did you use `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: ya i have done this. but its not working. even i  $chmod 777 interfaces also not working. (it is a owner file) can i login as root(owner)??

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`, and `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf`  that should let you edit the files.

If that doesn't work, try `sudo su` enter your password, and try editing the files that way.

Comment: can i edit it using text file?

Comment: You can do `sudo su`, and then `gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the desktop edition, you could also right click on the Network-Manager icon at the top right. (It should look like a little computer, Wi-Fi symbol, or a set of up/down arrows) In the menu that pops up choose "edit connections". Then enter your information in a manner similar to Windows.

If you're using server, and have no graphical interface installed you might try 
 `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo nano /etc/resolve.conf`

`Control` + `O` will write the changes and `Ctrl` + `X` will exit.

Hope this helps. Have a great day.